# Search a table for two matching values using a hash in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, sqlite

I have the following hash

```
{ "1" => "a", "2" => "a", "3" => "2"}
```

and the following sqlite3 table named ITEMS:

```
POSITION   CODE   NAME    VALUE
"1"        "a"    "Cat"   "Small"
"1"        "b"    "Cat"   "Big"
"2"        "a"    "Fish"  "Red"
"2"        "b"    "Fish"  "Blue"
"3"        "1"    "Car"   "Fast"
"3"        "2"    "Car"   "Slow"
```

I would like to query the table and return a hash of format {"NAME" => "VALUE"}.

The input hash is in the format {"POSITION" => "CODE"}, so the first value in the hash above has position "1" with code "a", which would return Name "Cat" and Value "Small".  The real version of this will have an initial hash of 20 values, and a table with closer to 200 records.

The example hash above should return:

```
{ "Cat" => "Small", "Fish" => "Red", "Car" => "Slow" }
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code :

```
Item.where("(POSITION = ? AND CODE = ?) OR
            (POSITION = ? AND CODE = ?) OR
            (POSITION = ? AND CODE = ?)", *hash.flatten
          )
     .select("name, value")
     .map { |rec| [rec.name, rec.value] }.to_h
```

**update**

As @mudasobwa [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301703/search-a-table-for-two-matching-values-using-a-hash-in-ruby-on-rails/29301797?noredirect=1#comment46800492_29301797)

```
Item.where((["(POSITION = ? AND CODE = ?)"] * hash.size).join(' OR '), hash.flatten)
    .select("name, value")
    .map { |rec| [rec.name, rec.value] }.to_h
```

This is a *wonderful* tip. I liked it too much.

Comment: If my string is a different length, will the where query have to be longer?

Comment: @sabrams Humm.. I don't know any better option with SQLite3 DB.. :(

Comment: @sabrams `(["(POSITION = ? AND CODE = ?)"] * hash.size).join(' OR '), hash.flatten` does the trick. Please note that splat in front of flattened array is superfluous.

Comment: Update your answer then :)

Comment: @mudasobwa sure.. why not.. :)